# Chart in jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts

I get user list from database in jsp. In each user I have a field named count. I have to show chart [pie and bar] for this count. I search on net found libraries for drawing chart in javascript but didn't get success in implementing them as I don't know how can I pass the values to the chart? Can any body recommend some good style to do this.

Note:- Any js or jquery chart library suggestion is welcome as far as they are free and commercially usable. Bar and pie charts are more preferable.

---

Edit:-

I know how to draw charts with predefined data. But here data is not predefined. My problem is how can I get counts in js. I'm getting list of users in jstl.

### How can I get counts for each user in js?

Comment: You can use jstl tags to substitute stuff inside your script tag.A combination of an iterator which will iterate through all the users , and the property tag should convert jstl data in objects into json.You might want to edit the question and add the relevant peices of jstl code so that users can help you more with tis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ### Any js or jquery chart library suggestion

I will suggest to use [JqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/) for drawing chart. They are simple and good looking charts.

> ### How can I get counts for each user in js?

You can easily use JSTL in javascript. What you need to do is just loop over your user list and add [username, usercount] pair in data of chart in javascript. A sample code can be ...

**Javascript**

```
$(function(){
    plot = $.jqplot("piePlot", [[ // --- loop over your user list using jstl and get data value pairs
                  <c:forEach items='${ userList }' var='user'>
                     ['${user.userName}',parseInt('${user.userCount}')],
                  </c:forEach>
               ]], { 
                    gridPadding: {top:0, bottom:38, left:0, right:0},
                    seriesDefaults:{
                          renderer:$.jqplot.PieRenderer, trendline:{show:true}, 
                          rendererOptions: { padding: 8, showDataLabels: true}},
                          legend:{
                                  show:true, 
                                  placement: 'inside', 
                                  rendererOptions: {
                                          numberRows: 1
                                  }, 
                          location:'s',
                          marginTop: '15px'
                   });
           });
```

Assuming count variable name is `userCount` and name of user is stored in `userName`. The list you get is named as `userList`.

**HTML**

```
<!-- div where chart will be shown -->
<div id="piePlot" style="margin-top:20px; margin-left:20px; width:200px; height:200px;">
</div>
```

**Files needed to be included in page**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jqPlot/jquery.jqplot.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqPlot/jquery.jqplot.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqPlot/plugins/jqplot.pieRenderer.min.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqPlot/excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
```

Comment: You should avoid using parseInt. Use Number instead, or at least pass a radix parameter to parseInt (read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend [Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) (http://code.google.com/p/flot/)

Comment: you can show it in a tooltip on the graph, this is inbuilt in flot, 

u can check this in the  "Interacting with the data points" example from the link I posted

Comment: @Naveen: I get user list in jstl. Now how can I get counts in js?

Comment: @mark I did not get you, do you want to show the count on the Graph or do u want to generate count for the users in js

Comment: check my sample code here http://jsfiddle.net/vdcUA/101/, tell me if this solves your problem.... This is some thing i was using in my application.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try Google Chart API (http://code.google.com/apis/chart/). Just build the url accordingly and supply "count" values as url string parameters. No need of javascript.

But, I guess your main issue is retrieving data available in jstl, to be used in javascript. This article may help you :

http://timothypowell.net/blog/?p=3

Just used the method described in this blog to store user and count information in a javascript array and then use it accordingly.

Comment: Yes that's what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use open flash chart.
It has libraries in almost all languages and uses flash to render charts.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/

Answer (score 0):

I never used it, but it seems really nice:

http://www.jqplot.com/tests/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery + jQplot should serve your purpose

Make a Ajax call from jQuery

```
(function($){
$.fn.loadBarChart = function(render_to,url){
    if ($(this).length) {
        return $.ajax({
                 url: $.url(url), //server side url which returns json data 
                 dataType: 'json',
                 success: function(data){
                    barchart(render_to,data);
                 },
                 error: function(status, statustatusText, responses, headers){
                    alert('Oops error occured..');
                 }
        });
    }
}
})(jQuery);
```

Get the json output from the server side in the below format:

> [["USER 1",44],["USER 2",20],["USER 3",15],["USER 4",11],["USER 5",4]]

plot the chart:

```
function barchart(render_to, data){
plot3 = $.jqplot(render_to, [data], {

    seriesDefaults: {
        renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
        rendererOptions: {
            fillToZero:true
        }
    },
    axes: {
        xaxis: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
        }
    }
});
}
```

This should work. More info [here](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/bar-charts.php)